# Lead name visible two times in lookup

Tags: lookup, page-layout

Guys I have an issue I have a Review lead object that has been created when any lead is converted. the review lead object have lookup of lead object. So after conversion of lead when review lead object is inserted then when i open that review lead record then i found on lookup field name is visible two times. Why what can be reason for this and how we can resolve same issue. For you reference screen shot is attached.

[image: Lead Layout]

Comment: Is this a standard conversion or a custom conversion? Do you have the lead's full name mapping to both the first and last name fields on your Review Lead object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the Name+Surname have the same value than the company Field of the referenced lead.

So it's just that whoever created this lead put on company the name+Surname also, not weird at all on Inbound Leads.